# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

```
    SELECT t0.testid,
 t0.pt500,
 t0.pt600,
 t1.id,
 t1.pt100,
 t1.pt200,
 t1.pt300  ,
     ( SELECT AVG(testid) FROM ab_Test ) AS testid_AVERAGE,
 ( SELECT MIN(testid) FROM ab_Test ) AS testid_MINIMUM,
 ( SELECT MAX(testid) FROM ab_Test ) AS testid_MAXIMUM,
 ( SELECT STDEV(testid) FROM ab_Test ) AS testid_STANDARDDEVIATION,
 ( SELECT SUM(testid) FROM ab_Test ) AS testid_TOTAL,
      ( SELECT COUNT(testid) FROM ab_Test ) AS testid_COUNT FROM sampletest t0
    Join ab_Test t1 ON (t0.testid=t1.id)
```

This is giving me error. my table structure is like below:

```
id pt100 pt200 pt300 inverter1 voltage1 
1   1   0   2   1   5   20  2   20  0   2016-02-23 16:33:10.080
2   0   0   2   1   5   20  2   20  0   2016-02-23 16:35:40.320
3   0   0   2   1   5   20  2   20  0   2016-02-23 16:39:26.860
4   0   0   2   1   5   20  2   20  0   2016-02-23 16:39:40.133
5   0   0   2   1   5   20  2   20  0   2016-02-23 16:42:20.407
testid pt500 pt600 cdt
1   3   5   2016-02-23 16:33:10.080
```

when i declare a join i am getting the error as in my question. why it is giving me error and if you can briefly explain me it will be very helpful. when i add group by like below:

```
group by t0.testid, t0.pt500, t0.pt600, t1.id, t1.pt100, t1.pt200, t1.pt300
```

I am getting following error.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I know its a duplicate question but i couldn't understand what the others had explained.

Comment: Which error are you getting, the one in the title or the one in the quoteblock?

Comment: the one in the title if i add a grouby clause to the query then i am getting error in quoteblock.

Answer (score 0):

Rather hard to figure out what you are doing but it is not correct the way you are doing it. I am guessing as to what you really want but I think this should be pretty close.

```
with TestValues as
(    
    SELECT testid 
        , AVG(testid) AS testid_AVERAGE
        , MIN(testid) FROM ab_Test AS testid_MINIMUM
        , MAX(testid) FROM ab_Test AS testid_MAXIMUM
        , STDEV(testid) FROM ab_Test AS testid_STANDARDDEVIATION
        , SUM(testid) AS testid_TOTAL
        , COUNT(testid) AS testid_COUNT
    FROM ab_Test
    group by testid
)

SELECT t0.testid
    , t0.pt500
    , t0.pt600
    , t1.id
    , t1.pt100
    , t1.pt200
    , t1.pt300  
FROM sampletest t0
Join ab_Test t1 ON t0.testid = t1.id
join TestValues tv on tv.testid = t0.testid
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help.. This code is not tested ..

```
SELECT t0.testid,
     t0.pt500,
     t0.pt600,
     t1.id,
     t1.pt100,
     t1.pt200,
     t1.pt300  ,
    AVG(testid)  AS testid_AVERAGE,
    MIN(testid)  AS testid_MINIMUM,
    MAX(testid)  AS testid_MAXIMUM,
    STDEV(testid) AS testid_STANDARDDEVIATION,
    SUM(testid)  AS testid_TOTAL,
    COUNT(testid AS testid_COUNT 
        FROM sampletest t0
        Join ab_Test t1 
        ON t0.testid=t1.id

        group by t0.testid, t0.pt500, t0.pt600, t1.id, t1.pt100, t1.pt200, t1.pt300
```

Comment: This is working can you help me understand the difference between avg(testid) as testid_average and ( SELECT top 1  MAX(testid) FROM ab_Test ) AS testid_MAXIMUM as when i replace it with top 1 then it is giving me the same result as your query

Comment: Its all depend on the data in the table. they testid values same for all the record then avg and max will be the same. Otherwise it should be diffrent.